# Code doesn't execute after socket.io emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I encounter a weird behaviour with socket.io. I set a custom emitter in client side and listening that event from server. Everything works fine. **But the code i write after emitter doesn't execute/invoke!** What can be possible reason(s) for this issue ? Here is my code:

```
console.log('---before socket emitter---');

this.socket.emit('stopStreaming', {});

console.log('---after socket emitter---');

this.stopStreamingUIUpdateHandler(grade, subject, batch, false);
```

console statement of `---before socket emitter---` execute but console statement of `---after socket emitter---` and `stopStreamingUIUpdateHandler` function doesn't execute/invoke.

Thank's

Updated: Here is the client side setup for socket.io

```
this.socket = io(serverAddress, {
   path: '/video-streaming',
   query: { param1, param2, param3, param4, param5 },
   reconnection: true,
   reconnectionDelay: 2000
});
```

**SOLVED**

There was race condition in my code, i accidentally disconnect my socket connection before executing `stopStreaming` event. So in server, this `stopStreaming` event didn't receive.

If someone face problem(s) like this, may be this question will be helpful.

Comment: have you got any error in the console ?

Comment: @BENARDPatrick no :(

Comment: Can you share more code, how do you set the `this.socket` ?

Comment: added the client side `this.socket` set up block of code.